# Fixing React Native CheckBox

Tags: javascript, react-native, checkbox

I have a React Native project. My understanding is that react native doesn't allow you to style checkboxes inherently, so I am using react-native-check-box and looking on expo.

When running I get "Unidentified is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.isChecked')"

I am using the exact suggested code from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-check-box#demo

What is going wrong?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, Image } from 'react-native';

import CheckBox from 'react-native-check-box';

import defaultStyles from "../../config/styles";

function AuthorizeInput () {

    return (

        <View style={defaultStyles.authorize}>
        <CheckBox
        style={{flex: 1, padding: 10}}
        onClick={()=>{
        this.setState({
                isChecked:!this.state.isChecked
            })
        }}
        isChecked={this.state.isChecked}
        />
        <Text style={defaultStyles.authText}>I am an authorized representative of this business.</Text>
        </View>
    );
}

export default AuthorizeInput;
```

Answer (score 0):

With functional components u can't use `this.setState` (only with class ones). However you can use `useState` [hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html). For example:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Text, View, Image } from "react-native";

import CheckBox from "react-native-check-box";

import defaultStyles from "../../config/styles";

function AuthorizeInput() {
  // default value is false
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

  return (
    <View style={defaultStyles.authorize}>
      <CheckBox
        style={{ flex: 1, padding: 10 }}
        onClick={() => setChecked(!checked)}
        isChecked={checked}
      />
      <Text style={defaultStyles.authText}>
        I am an authorized representative of this business.
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
}

export default AuthorizeInput;
```